# Find and list all MySQL tables accessed within scripts

Tags: mysql, sql, parsing, search, find

We are restructuring our database and we need to find all tables that are being referenced within our PHP scripts. I was considering a SQL Parser but I need to know the specific files in which the tables occur in. It needs to find the table `contacts` in both cases below, and then list the script location.

```
SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE...
SELECT * FROM `contacts` WHERE...
```

Comment: If nothing else you could do a brute force approach: get a list of tables from the information_schema database, then use that list with a bash script that performs a grep for each table name over your source tree. There will likely be some "noise" in the results if your table names are common words but you'll get a list of all references to all tables along with the filename.

Comment: Great idea Benny. However, something more accurate would be ideal. I can foresee a lot of "noise" as you put it with our table names.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't think of a better, more accurate, approach. When you run grep against your source tree for all the table names you can pipe that output to a file and then come up with some other search methods (perhaps with a text editor) that will allow you to sift through the "noise" easier. Searches for `FROM $table` or `UPDATE $table` would be a start but I would still want to look at all the lines just to make sure I hadn't missed some oddball SQL statement.

Comment: Benny Hill thank you for following up! I will try this, I was hoping there would be a parameter you can set in the MySQL general query log that would output the queries hit and the pages executing the query but I haven't found anything yet. Another method is to grep for all MySQL queries, then run the list of queries through a SQL parser to pull all tables hit. The problem with this is you won't have the scripts location where these queries exist, which does me no good.

Comment: You also need to think about "dead" code. You could have a query somewhere in a file that is no longer used. If that query happens to contain a table name that isn't used anywhere else you will be able to delete that table from the database during your restructuring. You've got an interesting (though tedious) problem. I think the reason it doesn't come up more often is because companies just don't bother with this kind of maintenance (to their detriment). They don't address these problems unless they change database systems, programming platforms, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try PHPStorm.  There is a feature on it called 'Database tools'.  Once configured, you can use the 'Find Usages' function to trace all of your table references in your project

More info [here](http://blog.jetbrains.com/webide/2012/11/sql-support-and-database-tools/)